# Sorting a linked list with different type of struct

Tags: c, sorting, struct, linked-list

im currently trying to sort a linked list, i have 3 different variable of struct while im sorting variable **hargabarang**, they are sorting properly , but the other variable is stay at their place(variable **namabarang** and **idbarang** ), not following the sorted variable.

heres the current code im working on

```
struct barang{
    char namabarang[MAX];
    int hargabarang;
    int idbarang;
    struct barang* next;
};
struct barang *head;

void sorthargaascending()
{
        struct barang *current = head, *index = NULL;
        int temp;

        if(head == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            while(current != NULL) {
                index = current->next;

                while(index != NULL) {
                    if(current->hargabarang > index->hargabarang) {
                        

                        //POINT
                        temp = current->hargabarang;
                        current->hargabarang = index->hargabarang;
                        index->hargabarang = temp;
                    }
                    index = index->next;
                }
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
}
```

i know i can add the other variable while swapping **hargabarang** (at //POINT) like this

```
                temp = current->**othervariable**;
                current->**othervariable**= index->**othervariable**;
                index->**othervariable**= temp;
```

But is there any more efficient way to do it???
i feel like this is not the most efficient way to do it

Comment: You can try to rearrange links instead of copying. You will need to store three links. The two being swapped and previous item next link to the latter item.

Comment: If you're manipulating order of nodes in a linked list data structure , the only elements you should be modifying are *pointers*. Drawing boxes and arrows on a piece of paper/whiteboard will help a lot, as will any remedial data structures book detailing linked list operations.